# ios requires reCAPCHA every time w/ firestore auth (Flutter)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I am using phone verification in my flutter app. My goal is to have the following flow: 1. user enters phone number 2. user is sent verification code 3. user enters code and is signed in. On android, that is the flow I get. On ios, however, it goes 1. user enters phone number 2. reCAPCHA page opens to make sure I'm not a robot 3. user is sent verification code 4. user enters code and is signed in (this happens on ios emulator). I want to get rid of the reCAPCHA page. Some people recommended that I turn on "remote-notifications", so I tried to do this in Xcode by adding it as a "capability" to my runner, and now my Info.plist includes

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
```

Which seems right. However, this did not fix the issue, and I am still faced with the capcha.

Version of firebase auth:

```
firebase_auth: 0.15.4
```

Output of flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/gollyzoom/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 months ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gollyzoom/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 38.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max         • B3536B50-C435-4442-9CF4-69D470B979CA • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

I would really appreciate if anyone had some advice on this!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution for my problem in Android https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4189#issuecomment-741711350

Steps made by @Omrankabalan

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/

If you have a Firebase project you can open in from here

[image]

Then select All tab and choose your existing project

[image]

Then go to API & Services => Library
Search for 'Android Device Verification'

[image]

Enable it

[image]

In Firebase make sure to add SHA-256 In Project Settings

[image]
[image]

Test it on a real device

Answer (score 1):

This happens to be in Android as well. I get the reCaptcha opened before I can enter my verification code.

Comment: Same here and I know why is it. It is because of addition of `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'` in app level build gradle dependencies. BUT for me app crashes on removing it. I don't know why?

Comment: It looks like something they have implemented in their last version. I dont know if someone can revert back to older version and if that will work. Thanks for your reply. I created a ticket with flutter support anyway.

Comment: hey could you give updates to what happened, what did they say ? is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I am still talking to the flutter support and created a MCVE for them and will keep that ticket updated.

Comment: @FaizanKamal I'm geeting error on removing =>implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'

I've already added SHA-1 and SHA-256. Still it's opening recaptcha view in browser.

Did you find any solution?

Thanks

Comment: @AhmedFathy Did you find anything useful?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and was able to solve it by modifying the entitlements. I have added 'Push Notifications' and 'Background Modes'. The background mode is set with "Background fetch" and "Remote notifications" options.

my "Info.plist" looks as follows after the 'Background Modes' change:

```xml
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Needless to say that you need to configure the push notifications from your developer account and to configure it from the firebase console for you iOS app.

[image: push notifications]
[image: background mode]
[image: background mode options]

Comment: This comment, saved my life. Thank you

Comment: That is one beauty of the internet, isn't it!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup Silent Push Notification for iOS.

Referencing this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

You will see there are 2 strategies when authorizing Phone Numbers: reCaptcha (to verify you are not a robot) and Silent Push Notifications.

There are additional configurations but in summary:

1. In Xcode, enable push notifications for your project.
2. Upload your APNs authentication key to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks but we are more concerned with Android than IOS. I have seen the one about IOS but that behavior with Android is so stange.