# Firebase (Flutter) authenticate phone number always requires reCAPTCHA

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

### Desired Result

Be able to [authenticate a user via phone number](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/#setup) on a flutter app running on a physical iPhone without seeing the reCAPTCHA screen

### Actual Results

Am able to authenticate but every time I do I see the reCAPTCHA even though I have silent notifications enabled

### Problem summary

I'm trying to setup my Flutter/Firebase app to authenticate via phone number on my iPhone. I have it working, but every time it authenticates it uses the [reCAPTCHA verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#set-up-recaptcha-verification) instead of the desired [silent notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#start-receiving-silent-notifications) process. In the error outputted in Android Studio is shown in the **Console Output** section below

#### Extra information

I started with this [firebase tutorial](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/#setup) to get the basic phone auth up and running. Then I followed this section to [enable app verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#enable-app-verification) on the iOS platform. That's when I started running into issues with only being able to validate using `reCAPTCHA`

I've been searching all over the internet and have seem similar questions but none of them have answered the problem...

- [AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892110/ax-lookup-problem-errorcode1100-errorpermission-denied-portnamecom-apple-i)
- [ios requires reCAPCHA every time w/ firestore auth (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766258/ios-requires-recapcha-every-time-w-firestore-auth-flutter)

#### Console Output

In the output block below it mentions `error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver'` but I have absolutely no idea what `com.apple.iphone.axserver` would be or what to modify to fix the issue.

```
[AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: Runner
7.11.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "deep_link_id" = "https://gladly-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/callback?authType=verifyApp&recaptchaToken=really long token. if it's required I can add it...";
}
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:407 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5aeca9c 4000B9C5-BBB5-3718-8002-F2350DA460F9 + 346780
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9bb58 _AXGetPortFromCache + 548
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9d1a0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 460
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001d025355c FEF8F17C-E529-34BE-91B9-D492B253DB94 + 853340
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a32b0 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 393904
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a4298 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 397976
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788034c 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 250700
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000187880e34 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 253492
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788a674 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 292468
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff715bc _pthread_wqthread + 272
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff7486c start_wqthread + 8
)
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:407 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5aeca9c 4000B9C5-BBB5-3718-8002-F2350DA460F9 + 346780
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9bb58 _AXGetPortFromCache + 548
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9d1a0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 460
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001d025355c FEF8F17C-E529-34BE-91B9-D492B253DB94 + 853340
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a32b0 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 393904
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a4298 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 397976
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788034c 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 250700
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000187880e34 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 253492
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788a674 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 292468
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff715bc _pthread_wqthread + 272
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff7486c start_wqthread + 8
)
[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver' PID:407 (
    0   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5aeca9c 4000B9C5-BBB5-3718-8002-F2350DA460F9 + 346780
    1   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9bb58 _AXGetPortFromCache + 548
    2   AXRuntime                           0x00000001a5a9d1a0 AXUIElementPerformFencedActionWithValue + 460
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001d025355c FEF8F17C-E529-34BE-91B9-D492B253DB94 + 853340
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a32b0 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 393904
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001878a4298 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 397976
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788034c 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 250700
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000187880e34 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 253492
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018788a674 16C9F613-7AE3-32CE-BA3A-B0DCF0464F0E + 292468
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff715bc _pthread_wqthread + 272
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001cff7486c start_wqthread + 8
)
```

Comment: Once you have 15 reputation, you can [post an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out all I had to do was add the key/value pair to the info.plist which was suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766258/ios-requires-recapcha-every-time-w-firestore-auth-flutter) post

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I added this But not working

Comment: Thank you for your link. It worked but there is some additional work I needed to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766258/ios-requires-recapcha-every-time-w-firestore-auth-flutter => follow this for the solution.